# Cardinality of set of all monotone increasing functions between $\Bbb N$

Tags: cardinals

Let $X =\{f:\Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb N\mid f \text{ is monotone increasing function}\}$

Then want to find the $card(X)$

First what I know is function $f$ is equal to the monotone increasing sequence that is defined on $\Bbb N$

and I want to find any set which can be mapped from X to the set which would be injective and also another set which can be mapped from that set to X which would be injective.

Any suggestion for those kind of sets?

Answer (score 3):

Do you know how many functions there are $\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$?  For any $f$ in your set, we can have $g(1)=f(1), g(n)=f(n)-f(n-1)$  This is a bijection between the $f$s and $g$s and I claim the $g$s are all functions $\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$.  The bijection also says the set of $g$s could be your $X$.

Comment: So you mean.. there's no way to specify the cardinality of my set X?

Comment: Sure there is.  The set of functions from $A$ to $B$ has cardinaltiy $|B|^{|A|}$ so your set $X$ has cardinality $|\Bbb N|^{|\Bbb N|}=\mathfrak c$

Comment: is $\frak c = 2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: Yes, it is.  It is the cardinality of the reals.

Answer (score 2):

Think about the functions that have this property:
$$f(n)\in\{2n-1,2n\}$$
for all $n$. Are these automatically increasing? How many of them are there?

Comment: I could easily imagine one such as f(n) = 2n-1 when n is odd number and f(n) =2n when n is even number. but how many of all f(n) that satisfies that property? .. that's tough